# Copyright messages in questions and answers

Tags: discussion, edits

What is the policy on copyright messages in questions or answers?  A recently posted question included a very long code sample, only 3 lines of which were relevant. Normally I would just edit the code. But a large part of the code sample was a long copyright message. I'm nervous about deleting copyright messages. What to do?

Answer (score 7):

Just delete irrelevant distractions, including copyright notices.

Posts to the Stack Exchange network are licensed under the CC Wiki license. If the OP posted enough copyrighted code for them to be in breach of the license, then that is *their* problem, not ours. The original copyright holder could always issue a DMCA takedown request to have the post removed.